# Enabling auto-login removed account from administrator groups

Tags: windows-7, privileges, auto-login

I'm really not very good at windows (windows7 home premium in this case).  I wanted to make it so my mom's new computer would auto login on boot.  I followed some instructions that started with "control userpasswords2".  I then unchecked the "users must use password" checkbox.  Problem solved, right?

Yeah, it worked great, but now UAC won't let me do admin things.  It says I should enter an addmin password, but there's no password box.  I popped back to the login screen (where she apparently does still need to use her password, which is what I expected) but the admin account is completely disabled.

So, is there any way to get her account back in the admin group?  Is there any way to enable the admin account?

I'm prepared to run the rescue disk, but I'd really rather not because I just got this machine set up for her and it would mean redoing hours of crapware removal and printer driver installs.  If I have to do it, now's the time I suppose.

Comment: What instructions did you follow? Why don't you just give her a blank password?

Comment: I wanted her to have an actual password because I wanted RDP to work (with a password) for her account.  XP can be made to work this way with tweakUI.  I was just going to familiar route.  But that's really not the problem I'm facing right now. The problem is that I lost admin. I followed these directions: http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/coolstuff/Tip-Auto-Login-Your-Windows-7-User-Account

Comment: I guess it automatically removes the user from the administrator group, I'm not sure. You might want to create a separate administrator account for RDP. Have you tried booting from Safe Mode to see if it lists an administrator account? Ah, TweakUI, did you do anything user-management related with it?

Comment: It's way too late to add more accounts in the traditional sense.  Had I done that (and I normally would have, so this is clearly pre-ordained), I wouldn't be having a problem right now.  Safe mode does not appear to have admin rights, it logs in as my mom.  Adminless.

Comment: Also, I did not use teakui.  I typed the couple things I said I typed in the first paragraph.  The question is not how to handle RDP, or how to do autologins, or what user management tools work best, the question is, now that there's no administrator, do I have to reinstall windows?  Is there some way to rescue this machine?  I could fix this in lunix in one boot cycle, but I'm no good at windows.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Our community is all about learning, in order to do so, we need to know what mistake happened along the path. And as said, safe mode works and we avoid `ntpasswd` because of the resulting permission problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Booting in Safe Mode [will *always* allow logins](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814777) with the built-in `Administrator` account, even if it is disabled or locked-out.

[ntpasswd](http://www.pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) can be used to unlock accounts as well. (It can promote users to Admins, too, but I do not recommend doing this, as group memberships will be messed up.)

Comment: oh, sweet.  I should have tried that.  I'm back in.  Thanks.